# PHP soap wrong digest hash

Tags: php, xml, soap, hash

I'm trying to send a SOAP message from PHP to a server, and I'm stuck at generating a SHA256 hash of the data being sent. Here is an example request provided by server owner:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-16FE2A6FC1AFE42BE9146412186273511">...</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-16FE2A6FC1AFE42BE9146412186273615">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">...</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-16FE2A6FC1AFE42BE9146412186273614">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>/CJj9686ARgbV/YmDrr+1yhcaJuXu022cADK/M8efQs=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>
                    Ii+W0EB2V6GJo4jMGwK1HCRdt6+r9TkgfhXyAuY8FNCXhPOtfoUi/Bw31U4Hm7SLscM/8klrQI3Z2vSfdNe3oDi1cm2Qouv1sOBK17VSg/IgKN92BC8kUaoF5W5ZBEcZr0WHjDWasSYEerZQ3Q+ZIJzt6cbS+cLZfQkLFg1UDOi5qLUkWE1pQ9AVYCvwrOFj/hFQx5koQTpigyG/DPlyoh2xOh/DAh6U/P5p+IiQwwCMdo1Rh2czUVpRCr3Cnz97AlQ8G6IGAtWNykXorVYZ1tGnXEaRngzjsn5RE/zCcRkqRpFaiEQuYly1I6YtFOEYIPXskE5oMZkCLINebu1Law==
                </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-16FE2A6FC1AFE42BE9146412186273512">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STR-16FE2A6FC1AFE42BE9146412186273513">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-16FE2A6FC1AFE42BE9146412186273511" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-16FE2A6FC1AFE42BE9146412186273614">
        <Trzba xmlns="http://fs.mfcr.cz/eet/schema/v2">
            <Hlavicka dat_odesl="2016-09-19T19:06:37+01:00" prvni_zaslani="false" uuid_zpravy="9edeb22b-4234-4047-869c-3a76f86c20d3"/>
            <Data celk_trzba="34113.00" cerp_zuct="679.00" cest_sluz="5460.00" dan1="-172.39" dan2="-530.73" dan3="975.65" dat_trzby="2016-01-05T00:30:12+01:00" dic_popl="CZ00000019" id_pokl="/5546/RO24" id_provoz="273" porad_cis="0/6460/ZQ42" pouzit_zboz1="784.00" pouzit_zboz2="967.00" pouzit_zboz3="189.00" rezim="0" urceno_cerp_zuct="324.00" zakl_dan1="-820.92" zakl_dan2="-3538.20" zakl_dan3="9756.46" zakl_nepodl_dph="3036.00"/>
            <KontrolniKody>
                <pkp cipher="RSA2048" digest="SHA256" encoding="base64">
                    W7UlA4hXNsDLvCj/eeRAYeOAsNsgMSdltcJNIW98KQRsfspTMW0Lr/OGQgRHZfO5KjolZgzN3k9mgzrVoX2+N90fCNEnOri2kjrW5vzTgMK6OZ9IryAEg0xFZjjjCQ0qKsQsVi8OLQOn3ZnN/BUGG2SIduER+iIOrhfOmes7OXaa5/2jQSfPTHZHZ/Bxhqld3gL4PHvd7sevZYUupHpE1fM7Uw1+lu8i1YOdghZoMyOfKw7FcqvRJpHrW/JZL5Dr5iCgu5ClmhZrb3hZavsxlDG7P2cUhSQgmEVTxJ2n38q/Cf91KE8e52SODN4Q8BfncXpmtkQ7Go3KsRsY3xN7xg==
                </pkp>
                <bkp digest="SHA1" encoding="base16">1F1A2D90-4EAD34A8-411CFB0B-EB17616E-B2CE8114</bkp>
            </KontrolniKody>
        </Trzba>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here my code:

```
$text = '<Trzba xmlns="http://fs.mfcr.cz/eet/schema/v2"><Hlavicka dat_odesl="2016-09-19T19:06:37+01:00" prvni_zaslani="false" uuid_zpravy="9edeb22b-4234-4047-869c-3a76f86c20d3"/><Data celk_trzba="34113.00" cerp_zuct="679.00" cest_sluz="5460.00" dan1="-172.39" dan2="-530.73" dan3="975.65" dat_trzby="2016-01-05T00:30:12+01:00" dic_popl="CZ00000019" id_pokl="/5546/RO24" id_provoz="273" porad_cis="0/6460/ZQ42" pouzit_zboz1="784.00" pouzit_zboz2="967.00" pouzit_zboz3="189.00" rezim="0" urceno_cerp_zuct="324.00" zakl_dan1="-820.92" zakl_dan2="-3538.20" zakl_dan3="9756.46" zakl_nepodl_dph="3036.00"/><KontrolniKody><pkp cipher="RSA2048" digest="SHA256" encoding="base64">W7UlA4hXNsDLvCj/eeRAYeOAsNsgMSdltcJNIW98KQRsfspTMW0Lr/OGQgRHZfO5KjolZgzN3k9mgzrVoX2+N90fCNEnOri2kjrW5vzTgMK6OZ9IryAEg0xFZjjjCQ0qKsQsVi8OLQOn3ZnN/BUGG2SIduER+iIOrhfOmes7OXaa5/2jQSfPTHZHZ/Bxhqld3gL4PHvd7sevZYUupHpE1fM7Uw1+lu8i1YOdghZoMyOfKw7FcqvRJpHrW/JZL5Dr5iCgu5ClmhZrb3hZavsxlDG7P2cUhSQgmEVTxJ2n38q/Cf91KE8e52SODN4Q8BfncXpmtkQ7Go3KsRsY3xN7xg==</pkp><bkp digest="SHA1" encoding="base16">1F1A2D90-4EAD34A8-411CFB0B-EB17616E-B2CE8114</bkp></KontrolniKody></Trzba>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($text);

$text = $doc->C14N(true, true);

$hash = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $text, true));

echo $hash;
```

But I'm getting this hash: `sQMcQ4plFh9J9ovXzCUmVcMPofSWlr93Ag+72o8761o=`, however according to the example document, I should get this: `/CJj9686ARgbV/YmDrr+1yhcaJuXu022cADK/M8efQs=`.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As it turn out, my C14N method does [absolutely nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204947/php-domdocument-c14n-canonization-does-absolutely-nothing), so that's likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but...

But I write here because I have the same issue even I use base64_encode()
I find a digested value but not the same as example.

But I don't know if I must encode my data on UTF-8 before like that

`$digestedValue = base64_encode(hash('sha256',utf8_encode($doxXml->C14N()),true));`

Or like that with another function

`$digestedValue = base64_encode(openssl_digest(utf8_encode($doxXml->C14N()),'sha256',true));`

Using encode_utf8() changes the digested value if any characters that need to be encoded in UTF8 are present... So... Should we use... or not?

Comment: I always know this post is old and I answer himself but...
I write because I had to to sign an XML. So I had to generate a digest value.
And after many tests I found the RobRichards library to do that (RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\)
And I was succeed with it. So I want to share this information